# How to import a variable from another function and another class?

Tags: python

I'm trying but it's not working. I have the following code line:

```
class Run:
    def Method(self, choice):
        print "%sZip        :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.start().LoadJson['zip'])
```

And this is variable, and is within another class, and another function:

```
class Host_Method:
    def start(self):
        My_API =    requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/%s" % socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[2]))
        LoadJson =  json.loads(My_API.content)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "InfoIP.py", line 78, in <module>
    elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "-h": Run().Method(Host_Method())
  File "/Pentest/InfoIP2/Libraries/InfoIP_Functions.py", line 159, in Method
    print "%sZip        :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['zip'])
AttributeError: Host_Method instance has no attribute 'LoadJson'
```

Comment: Maybe you need a `return` statement in `start` method, and return the `LoadJson`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want them to be stored in an instance variable (`self....`). And you probably want your start to be an `__init__` method. Your corrected class could look like:

```
class HostMethod:
    def start(self):
        self.my_API = requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/{0}".format(socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[2])))
        self.load_json = json.loads(self.my_API.content)
```

Then, you could do:

```
class Run:
    def Method(self, choice):
        print "{0}Zip        :\t{1}{2}\n".decode('utf-8').format(Basic_Green, White, choice.load_json['zip'])

a = Run()
a.method(HostMethod())
```

See also:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html